# converting c-mode hooks to use-package fails in non-obvious ways

Tags: use-package, cc-mode

Emacs version 26.3 on a mac

I have this (simplified) c(c)-mode config:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (c-set-style "bsd")))
```

which works when I visit a c file.

When I convert to

```
(use-package cc-mode
   :config
   (c-set-style "bsd")
  )
```

and restart emacs, this snippet gets applied to the *scratch* buffer and I get this odd error:

> `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Buffer *scratch* is not a CC Mode buffer (c-set-style)")`

The scratch buffer is shown as a Fundamental buffer, not an interactive-lisp buffer.
Strangely, any added config, even a `:bind  (("C-c t" . tags-search))` fixes this.

So, with this,

```
(use-package cc-mode
  :bind  (("C-c t"         . tags-search))
  :config
  (c-set-style "bsd")
)
```

when I visit a c file, say `foo.c`, I now get

> `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Buffer foo.c is not a CC Mode buffer (c-set-style)")`
>   The buffer/file is loaded, but the mode is Fundamental.

Is there a good way to use use-package with cc-mode, given that it supports modes for many different types of code and separable hooks for a lot of these?

Thanks,

Kannan

Comment: If you just want to have some configuration running, after your package has loaded (and such configuration that does not require a running buffer with the package's mode), then you might use "eval-after-load".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code after `:config` runs as soon as the package is loaded, which is when you config file is loaded unless you delay loading the package somehow. So the `c-set-style` function is getting called somewhere except a `c-mode` file and triggering an error before Emacs is even able to switch `*scratch*` into the proper mode.

Adding `:bind` appears to fix the problem as `:bind` implies `:defer`, which delays loading the package until needed.

`use-package` doesn't remove the need for hooks, it just changes where you define them.  Put your `add-hook` in the `:config` section of `use-package`

```
(use-package cc-mode
   :config
   (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
    (lambda ()
       (c-set-style "bsd")))
  )
```

Comment: Kannan Varadhan: Note also that the lambda form is not quoted, which is as it should be -- don't quote your lambdas.  But also, don't use lambdas with hooks at all.  Use a named function instead -- it avoids lots of potential problems with updating/removing hook functions, inspecting hook variables, and visiting the function definitions.

Comment: That works.  Quick question:  do I then move the config section into the add-hook, now that I need it at least one piece of the configuration?   I didnt need it for other uses earlier...

Comment: @phils Thanks, that is a good tip.    Not quoting the lambda form, I will use.  Not sure why i got into that habit, I think I pulled it from somewhere and never thought about it.   Not everything works for me as you suggested though.  I tried: `  (defun kv-style () "test" (c-set-style "bsd"))
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (kv-style))
  `  and ran into the same issue.

Comment: You don't need to move any other config.  Think about it this way: `add-hook` is just setting a variable (`c-mode-common-hook`). And you set it alongside all of you `setq`s in the `:config` section.  If you use a named function you just pass the function,  but don't evaluate it: `(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'kv-style)`.  I would just use a lambda myself; I find it easier to read